How I can index collection's intances in geometry node?
I don't know how to use Geometry Node, but I need to apply a Invisible material to all the objects in a collection but one. It's a bunch of face expressions so it's a plus if I can select Left and Right eyes individually. Thanks in advance.


I think we need to know something about the organization of your collection.. what it contains, which bits of it we might be selecting

Answer here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/319341/how-can-i-select-objects-in-collection-to-be-visible-with-geometry-nodes/319355#319355

(1) Do you mean "Answer to Robin Betts question" (and the Blender file to work with is in the other linked post), or "Answer to your question" (and this one is some kind of duplicate) ? (2) By "Invisible material", do you mean "Transparent", or do you "just" want to hide/reveal objects in a collection ?

Seems pretty straightforward. Something like this. It will find whatever materials you have assigned and replace them if it finds them, do nothing if not.


But I need to select a object inside the collection to replace the material only on that selected object

You can't use GN to do that AFAIK. At least you couldn't in a way that isn't any easier than just manually editing the materials on the object itself.
