How can I select objects in collection to be visible with Geometry Nodes?
I want to create expressions set to make animations, but I want to swap between them easily with Geometry Nodes or any other add-on available, any idea? Thanks in advance.



Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Yes, already did it

You should be able to put the objects for the two expressions into two separate collections (e.g., "Eyes Open" and "Eyes Closed"), hide both those collections, and then use geometry nodes to select the desired collection to replace the "Face_Sets" geometry.  The setup would look like this:

Here's an updated Blend file. 

Edit:
To ease animation, a Switch node can be used for two expressions. For more than two, an Index Switch node should be considered:


I took the liberty to edit your answer instead of writing a new one as mine is merely a slight variation from yours. Feel free to remove it if it bothers you.

Thanks you both, with this I´ll be able to do the animations that Im looking for!

@EdgarMontesdeOca: May I recommend to apply this : What should I do when someone answers my question?
